# How do you make a raycast at the mouse position and then get coordinates for use in terrain?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a runtime terrain editor and my raycasts are broken. How do I raycast at the mouse position and then get coordinates that I can use to grow my terrain?

I've tried the raw mouse position, which was only slightly inaccurate, and then I tried `Input.GetAxis()` and `Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay()`.

```c#
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        print("Got Ray" + ray.ToString());
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Terrain>())
            {
                Terrain terrain 
                hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Terrain>();
                TerrainData data = terrain.terrainData;
                float height = data.GetHeight(
                    (int)Math.Round((double)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x), 
                    (int)Math.Round((double)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y));

                data.SetHeightsDelayLOD((int)Math.Round(
                    (double)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint( Input.mousePosition).x), 
                    (int)Math.Round((double)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y), 
                    new float[3, 3] 
                    { 
                        { height + 1.0f / 240000.0f, height + 1.0f / 240000.0f, height + 1.0f / 240000.0f }, 
                        { height + 1.0f / 240000.0f, height + 1.0f / 240000.0f, height + 1.0f / 240000.0f }, 
                        { height + 1.0f / 240000.0f, height + 1.0f / 2400.0f, height + 1.0f / 2400.0f } 
                    });

                terrain.ApplyDelayedHeightmapModification();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that the terrain would grow at the mouse position, but it does not grow at all.

Comment: Are you trying to sculpt or deform the terrain at runtime?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to sculpt the terrain at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

[Terrain data.GetHeight](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.GetHeight.html):

> **xBase**: First x **index** of heightmap samples to retrieve.

-> `GetHeight` doesn't expect world coordinates but data indexes!

---

You have to calculate which index is at the hit point of the ray (not the mouse position):

```c#
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    print("Got Ray" + ray.ToString());
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Terrain>())
        {
            Terrain terrain 
            hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Terrain>();

            TerrainData data = terrain.terrainData;

            //
            // !!! Mouse position to terrain coordinates
            //
            var point = hit.point;
            var xResolution = data.heightmapWidth;
            var zResolution = data.heightmapHeight;
            var terX =(int)((point.x / data.size.x) * xResolution);
            var terZ =(int)((point.z / data.size.z) * zResolution);

            var height = data.GetHeight(terX, terZ);

            // Same when you set values
            var newValues = new float[3, 3] 
            { 
                { height + 1.0f / 240000.0f, height + 1.0f / 240000.0f, height + 1.0f / 240000.0f }, 
                { height + 1.0f / 240000.0f, height + 1.0f / 240000.0f, height + 1.0f / 240000.0f }, 
                { height + 1.0f / 240000.0f, height + 1.0f / 2400.0f, height + 1.0f / 2400.0f } 
            };
            data.SetHeightsDelayLOD(terX, terZ, newValues);
            terrain.ApplyDelayedHeightmapModification();
        }
    }
}
```

([Source](https://forum.unity.com/threads/edit-terrain-in-real-time.98410))